# Cannot Implicitly convert type 'System.collections.generic.IEnumerable<Project.Dto.PaymentDto>'to'string'

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I hava a class and controller as below

```
 //class
 public class Payment
{  
    public Guid ID { get; set; }
    public string InvoiceNumber { get; set; }
    public string ContactNumber { get; set; }
    public string ConsumerName { get; set; }
}

//controller
public class TransPaymentController : Controller
{

     public ActionResult Searching(int? page,string searchInvoiceNumber)
    {

        //Page Setting
        int pageSize = 10;
        int pageNumber = (page ?? 1);

        IPagedList<Payment> payments = null;
        payments= paymentRepo.GetList_Payments_InTableManualPayment(pageSize, pageNumber);


        if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(searchInvoiceNumber))
        {

            string data = payments.Where(s => s.InvoiceNumber.Contains(searchInvoiceNumber)); //the error is here

        }
        return null;
    }
}
```

and I get an error as below.

Cannot Implicitly convert type `System.collections.generic.IEnumerable<Project.Dto.PaymentDto> to string`

why am I getting this error?

Comment: you declared `data` as `string`. The `Where` does not return a string. What are you actually trying to get? This may be an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem).

Comment: As @Nkosi mentioned, `Where` would return an `IEnumerable` in your case. You can convert/project the source data type to target by using a projection like `Select` or `Aggregate` (Aggregate can join each item into a single string, and also there is an example on doing that in the documentation https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.aggregate?view=netframework-4.7.2) methods defined in LINQ.

Comment: If you replace `string data` by `var data` your error should disappear. But as the previous comments stated, it is unclear what you are trying to achieve here.

Comment: @Nkosi Even if this is an XY problem, the Y in this case is fairly fundamental to any prospective solutions to X.

Comment: With basic understanding of the C# language it should be obvious *why* you get the error. So I'm voting unclear what you are asking, as explaining *why* will likely not solve your problem.

Answer (score 0):

From the look of it, your controller is simply trying to look up an invoice number.  The nature of the error relating to converting a collection `IEnumerable<Project.Dto.PaymentDto>` to a single element `string`.

Consider what your query is asking the database:  Please find me any invoices where the invoice number contains `searchInvoiceNumber`.  The database may return zero, one or many results.  What would that look like as a string?  That's a nonsense question.

Try instead:

```
var data = payments.Where(s => s.InvoiceNumber.Contains(searchInvoiceNumber)).ToList();
```

Now data contains a zero, one or many `PaymentDto` items.  It's up to you to decide what to do with that.

Note that your `Payment` class isn't being used so far.  If you're trying to populate that directly from the query, that's probably a separate question.